# mat-slide-toggle does not consider checked binding

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular application with `mat-slide-toggle`

```
switchValue: {{ switch }} <br />
  <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="switch" (toggleChange)="toggle()">Toggle me!</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

and the component

```
  switch = false;

  toggle() {
    // perform backend request and do some heavy calculation here
    this.switch = false;
  }
```

As you can see the toggle does not set the `switch` property. But when the user now toggles the switch, the switch goes from `off` to `on`, however, the `switch` value is still `false`. Imho the switch should not change. Am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: From what I think, why not just set the toggle disabled if you don't want the toggle remain as the default state.

Comment: user clicks slider, I will do a backend request. backend will then set the switch' value and switch shall show the current switchValue. But as of now the switch is out of sync

Comment: In your `toggle()` function, you need to set the switch status based on your backend response.

Comment: thats the problem: when switchValue is false --> user toggles, switch displays true --> backend returns false. Then the switchValue is false but toggle displays true.

I updated my example above, thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the checkbox reference into the change method, and then set it to which ever state you want it to!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * @title Basic slide-toggles
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'slide-toggle-overview-example',
  template: `
  switchValue: {{ switch }} <br />
  <mat-slide-toggle #toggle [ngModel]="switch" (change)="toggleAction(toggle)"
    >Toggle me!</mat-slide-toggle
  >
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatSlideToggleModule, FormsModule],
})
export class SlideToggleOverviewExample {
  switch = false;

  toggleAction(toggle: any) {
    toggle.checked = false;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lhfvy5-dd12wf)